# How to parse a variable inside a string inside a CodeIgniter view?

Tags: php, codeigniter, templates, variable-assignment

I have function called get_variable which grabs the value of a variable from the database.

Let's say the value of my variable (stored in the db) is something like: "I like $fruit"

I would like to pass this string, WITH $fruit translated to the proper value, on to my view.

I have the following set up (pseudo code below):

```
$details['fruit'] = 'apples';
$details['test'] = get_variable('my_variable_name');

$var = $CI->load->view('viewname',$details,TRUE);
```

Problem is that what is outputting in my view ($var) is "I like $fruit"

What I want is "I like apples"

I feel like I'm missing a step here, perhaps with variable variables? (http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php), but not sure how to get it to behave. Any insight would be appreciated.

Comment: Can you post your view code?

Answer (score 0):

If you are sure the variables in the database are safe (Only you can change them), you can eval the code in your get variable function like this:

```
function get_variable($var, $data = array())
{
  // Here the code that gets the variable from the database
  $db_var = 'I like $fruit';
  extract($data);

  $return = '';
  eval('$return = "' . $db_var . '"');

  return $return;
}

// And then use this in the controller:
$details['test'] = get_variable('my_variable_name', $details);
```

But when the database variables are accessible by others, you really would not want to use eval (really don't!). Instead use some form of templating like "I like %fruit%" and make get_variable look like this:

```
function get_variable($var, $data = array())
{
  // Here the code that gets the variable from the database
  $db_var = 'I like $fruit';
  extract($data);

  $return = $db_var;
  foreach($data as $var => $value) {
    $return = str_replace('%'.$var.'%', $value, $return);
  }

  return $return;
}

// And then use the same method in the controller:
$details['test'] = get_variable('my_variable_name', $details); // This makes all variables in details available in the database variable
```